# vorbis_analysis generates access violation

Tags: audio, encoding, c++builder, oggvorbis, c++builder-xe7

I'm trying to create an .ogg file, but even the example code presented generates an Access Violation when calling `vorbis_analysis()`.

I'm using a simplified version of this encoding [Example](http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/vorbis/examples/encoder_example.c). I have tried the full example as it is, but I get the same error at the same place.

The code below is the example simplified by filling the encoding buffer with a constant instead of a wav file. The `hFile` is a `TStreamFile` instance created elsewhere.

```
vorbis_info      vi;
vorbis_dsp_state vd;
vorbis_comment   vc;
vorbis_block     vb;

ogg_stream_state os;
ogg_page         og;
ogg_packet       op;

ogg_packet header;
ogg_packet header_comm;
ogg_packet header_code;

int res;
int len  = 0;
int eos  = 0;
int loop = 0;

vorbis_info_init(&vi);
res = vorbis_encode_init_vbr(&vi,2,44100,0.4f);
res = vorbis_encode_setup_init(&vi);

vorbis_comment_init(&vc);
vorbis_comment_add_tag(&vc,"TITLE","Silent noise");
res = vorbis_analysis_init(&vd,&vi);
res = vorbis_block_init(&vd,&vb);

srand(time(NULL));
res = ogg_stream_init(&os,rand());
res = vorbis_analysis_headerout(&vd,&vc,&header,&header_comm,&header_code);
res = ogg_stream_packetin(&os,&header);
res = ogg_stream_packetin(&os,&header_comm);
res = ogg_stream_packetin(&os,&header_code);

/* This ensures the actual
 * audio data will start on a new page, as per spec
 */
while(ogg_stream_flush(&os,&og)) {
  hFile->Write(og.header,og.header_len);
  hFile->Write(og.body,  og.body_len  );
}

while(!eos) {
  float **Buffer = vorbis_analysis_buffer(&vd,1024);

  if(loop<10) {
    for(int n=0; n<1024; n++) {
      Buffer[0][n] = 1.0f;
      Buffer[1][n] = 1.0f;
    }
    res = vorbis_analysis_wrote(&vd,1024);
    loop++;
  } else {
    res = vorbis_analysis_wrote(&vd,0);
    eos = true;
  }

  // Enough data?
  while(vorbis_analysis_blockout(&vd,&vb) == 1) {
    res = vorbis_analysis(&vb,&op);  // <---- Access Violation
    res = vorbis_bitrate_addblock(&vb);

    while(vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket(&vd,&op)) {

      /* weld the packet into the bitstream */
      res = ogg_stream_packetin(&os,&op);

      /* write out pages (if any) */
      while(!eos){
        if(ogg_stream_pageout(&os,&og) == 0) {
          break;
        }
        hFile->Write(og.header,og.header_len);
        hFile->Write(og.body,  og.body_len  );

        /* this could be set above, but for illustrative purposes, I do
           it here (to show that vorbis does know where the stream ends) */
        if(ogg_page_eos(&og)) {
          eos=1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

res = ogg_stream_clear(&os);
res = vorbis_block_clear(&vb);
vorbis_dsp_clear(&vd);
vorbis_comment_clear(&vc);
vorbis_info_clear(&vi);
```

The first part runs fine, the header is created and saved to the stream. Then I just fill the buffer with 1.0 floats for test purposes.

When there is enough data available the call to `vorbis_analysis` always generate `Access Violation at x write of address x`

The variable `res` always indicate success all the way down to the access violation.

I'm using static linked libogg v1.3.2 and libvorbis 1.3.5

Comment: Could you try this but with a dynamically linked ogg/vorbis libraries? It might be that the problem is in the static-linked code, and not exactly on this, the calling code.

Comment: As a test, I compiled the example in Visual Studio 2013 and it worked fine there. So I think there might be something with my static lib that isn't right, as you also proposed.

Comment: the static lib, is it compiled with C++Builder, or somewhere else? I remember you asking about converting a lib into the C++Builder format. If it is compiled completely with C++Builder, maybe you can step into the function call and see internally where it is generating the AV, but I'm guessing that if this was the case you would have tried that already

Comment: I wanted to keep the libraries separated from the application, but It seems like I have to include the lib source and just skip the library thing. I'm debugging the whole library right now to see where it goes wrong... But since it works fine in VC i think it might be a compiler setting not being right. Maybe packed structs or alignment being off.

Comment: Did you have any success, I am getting same error access violation on vorbis_analysis_blockout after couple of runs?

Comment: I put that part of the project on ice for the moment, but no, I didn't solve it :(